# Plane orthogonal to the x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, orthogonality, electromagnetism

I am solving an image charge problem and the setting is that a grounded conducting plane is orthogonal to the $x$-axis at $x = 0$. There is a short line charge of length $L$ pointing in the $\hat{i}$-direction, starting at a distance $x_0 > 0$ away from the surface of the plane.

I am unsure about what a plane 'orthogonal' to the $x$-axis means. Is its normal vector  perpendicular to the $x$-axis or parallel to the axis?

Also, how is the given line charge oriented? Is it parallel or perpendicular to the $x$-axis?

I do not need to know how to use the method of images. I just need clarify the set-up. It is just a bit confusing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Plane orthogonal to $x$-axis means that the plane's normal vector is parallel to $x$-axis.

Comment: @Sfoo1  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plane orthogonal to a vector $\vec n(a,b,c)$ means that the vector is perpendicular to the plane, i.e. that the normal vector to the plane is parallel to the given vector.

In this case the equation of the plane is: $$ax+by+cz=d$$

Thus for a plane orthogonal to the x axis (1,0,0) the equation is:

$$x=d$$